# expected result not getting

Tags: mysql, tree, parent-child, hierarchical-data

i have three tables which are shown in this demo: **[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1635/3)**

These are expected conditions and result

[image]

Here you can check this `activity_id` and `region_id` in demo and get `unit_id` As `MEASUREMENT_UNIT_ID`.

What I tried so far:

```
select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
    from tree t
    left join product_autoselect_units u
    on t.parent_id = u.region_id
    or t.parent_id = u.activity_id
    or t.entity_id IN (ACtivity_id)
    left join units gu
    on u.id = gu.unit_id
    WHERE t.entity_id IN (Region_id)
```

query shown demo is getting this condition and result

[image]

so here for `activity_id`=5753 and `region_id`=10 not getting expected result. I want null values as results... you can check in the demo.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
i have tried you query on given link in your post

try to put your id for time being like in below query and see the result
select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
    from tree t
    left join product_autoselect_units u
    on t.parent_id = u.region_id
    or t.parent_id = u.activity_id
    or t.entity_id IN (ACtivity_id)
    left join units gu
    on u.id = gu.unit_id
where t.entity_id in (5742,5753)
  ##WHERE t.entity_id IN (Region_id)
```

Comment: thankx for help....but  here 5742 and 5753 both are activity ids...you can use one at a time...meas one activity_id and one region_id